# What does "a year of activity" mean?

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns

Can we say: ***a year/month/week of activity*** to express all of the activities happened in a particular time?

I think ***a year/month/week of doing something*** may have the same function.

But the meaning may change sometimes:

Like ***a year of harvesting.(it may refer to a particular time, not harvesting）， Am I right?***

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "it may refer to a particular time, not harvesting".  Can you clarify?  But in general, yes, you can use that phrasing.  For example, **"It was a year of great flooding in Slobovia"** can mean that there was a lot of flooding during that year, not necessarily that Slobovia was flooded for the entire year.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!!! a year of harvesting. Here I mean the year of harvesting, the year is featured of harvesting like :a story of olve